# Bash script - How to take todays date and count back monthly for a year

Tags: bash, shell, date, count, counter

I've made a bash script executing a PHP file:

```
#!/bin/bash
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-10-01 2010-11-01 
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-09-01 2010-10-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-08-01 2010-09-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-07-01 2010-08-01
```

etc... these dates have to go back until the end of the year. Now I can either simply have tons of lines in this script with those dates in there or have it count back until the end of this year (or one full year) from todays `date`

I just don't know how.

Comment: "Now I can either simply have tons of lines"??  By "tons" to you mean 12?

Comment: Yes I do mean 12... but maybe I'll be needing more because I've fixed this script to work for the period of this month... but it'll most likely be used next month... and the month after perhaps too, so I'll have to continue editing it

Answer (score 3):

No need for complicated logic and arithmetic. Don't run it around midnight or time changes or the last few days of the month.

```
#!/bin/bash
for m in {0..14}
do
    beg=$(date -d "now - $((m+1)) months" "+%Y-%m-%d")
    end=$(date -d "now - $m months" "+%Y-%m-%d")
    echo php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance "$beg" "$end"
done
```

Remove the `echo` to make it work

Example:

```
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-08-01 2010-09-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-07-01 2010-08-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-06-01 2010-07-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-05-01 2010-06-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-04-01 2010-05-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-03-01 2010-04-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-02-01 2010-03-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-01-01 2010-02-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2009-12-01 2010-01-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2009-11-01 2009-12-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2009-10-01 2009-11-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2009-09-01 2009-10-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2009-08-01 2009-09-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2009-07-01 2009-08-01
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2009-06-01 2009-07-01
```

Answer (score 1):

This script:

```
#!/bin/bash
let YEAR=$(date +%-Y)
let MONTH=$(date +%-m)
let DAY=$(date +%-d)

for ((m = MONTH; m < 12; m++)); do
    php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance "$YEAR-$((m))-$DAY" "$YEAR-$((m+1))-$DAY"
done
```

Executes these commands:

```
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-9-1 2010-10-1
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-10-1 2010-11-1
php upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance 2010-11-1 2010-12-1
```

I wasn't sure exactly what these dates mean, so there are probably some off-by-one errors.

Comment: Can't you have something like `%02d` to add that extra zero in the front. I remember having a similar problem with the `value too great for base` error, but somehow the `%` fixed it. Just a thought; I don't use bash much.

Comment: @vlad003: Just remove the dash from the date spec to get the leading zero: `+%m`

Answer (score 0):

Wow thanks for all your replies, I've ended up settling for something like this, it's been checked in, it's a little crude but does the job fine for my needs.

```
let YEAR=$(date +%-Y)
let MONTH=$(date +%-m)
let DAY=$(date +%-d)
for ((m = MONTH; m < 12 && m > 0; m--)); do
    php /srv/www/htdocs/$SCHOOL/tools/upgrade_attendance.php refresh_daily_attendance "$YEAR-$((m))-$DAY" "$YEAR-$((m+1))-$DAY"
done
```